# QT Creator project file: how to check for android arm vs x86

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator

In QT Creator .pro file done for an Android project I need to include different files based on target architecture (or compiler). In particular, for ARM and x86 architecture I need to include a different manifest.xml file, since I need to specify a different version code, as written in [Multiple APK guidelines](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html).

I need something like this:

```
android_armv7{
    DISTFILES += android/arm/AndroidManifest.xml
}
android_x86{
    DISTFILES += android/x86/AndroidManifest.xml
}
```

`android_armv7` and `android_x86` do not exist.

Moreover, how to check the architecture/compiler in C++ code too?

Comment: You want to detect the current architecture on which the Qt application is running using some method in C++ code ?

Comment: Yes, both in C++ code and .pro file

Answer (score 1):

You can use: (tested with Qt 5.9.2)

```
equals(QT_ARCH, arm): DISTFILES += android/arm/AndroidManifest.xml
equals(QT_ARCH, i386): DISTFILES += android/x86/AndroidManifest.xml
```

I'd had the same issue for setting library search paths.

Maybe this can help others when they find this question.